# Looking to search a spreadsheet for a value, then go to the value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet (not excel!),

I've got two sheets. one titled "Companies", one titled "Contacts"
The "companies" sheet is just a list of company names in the A column, nothing else.
The "contacts" sheet is a spreadsheet of contact details, but the company they work for is also in the A column.

I would like to figure out how to write a script that will look at the active cell's value (in the "companies" sheet), then search for that value in the company column of the "contacts" sheet, and then go to that cell in the second sheet and make it the active cell.

I've got some of it figured out; I'm having the most trouble with the section to search the "contacts" sheet's column A for a match in value, then going to that value to make it the active cell

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us the code that you have so far and we may be able to help..

Comment: I've got basically nothing at the moment for the section I need help with.

Making the code search for the same value as the active cell, then going to the row with the same value in the second sheet

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you want to look for a certain value in the contacts sheet based on the company?

Answer (score 1):

Paste the code below in your script editor, save it and refresh the spreadsheet. Click on the cell you want to search for in the 'Companies' sheet and then click the 'Custom functions' menu and 'Search for company'.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen(e) {
    ui.createMenu('Custom Functions')
    .addItem('Search for company', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi()
}

function myFunction() {
    var searchSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Companies');
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Contacts');

    var searchTerm = searchSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

    var searchRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < searchRange.length; i++) {
        if (searchTerm == searchRange[i][0]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    var row = targetSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1);

    targetSheet.setActiveRange(row);

}
```